# How to compare user input to class object data?

Tags: python

total beginner here.

I'm trying to understand how to compare user input data to preset class data. Let's say `class = Person`, with the age, weight, and name.

And I've got two people, `johnsmith = Person(50, 200, "John Smith")
tomjones = Person(40, 220, "Tom Jones")`

I want to prompt the user to input the name Tom, and have check all "name" attributes for the Person class. So something like,

`person = input(print("Insert the person's name: "))` entering "Tom" and then returning a list of all Toms for the user to select, or if there's only one, confirm that the user in fact did mean Tom Jones.

Should I create an array like `people = [tomjones, johnsmith, (etc)]`, and somehow search inside that?

Please point me in the right direction on this, thanks.

Comment: first of all you dont need to put `print` inside your `input`. hold all your `person` data in a collection of some sort, lets say a list. then all you need to do is `result = [dude for dude in person_list if dude.name == user_input]` of course adjust variable names to match your case

Comment: keep all `Person` on lists and then you can use `for`-loop to check name in every `Person`

Comment: Why are you not using a *dictionary*?

Answer (score 0):

> Should I create an array-like `people = [tomjones, johnsmith, (etc)]`, and somehow search inside that?

Yes.

Although ihough if you expect a very large number of "people" and frequent queries always on the same field (e.g. you're always searching for a specific person by its name) you may also want to create an *index* to speed up searches e.g. create a dict (possibly a `WeakValueDictionary`) which maps whatever your search key is to the proper person.

This is because iterating a list is cheap and efficient but going through the entire list is linear time (O(n)) so if your list is *very long* and you go through it a lot, it adds up. Building an index is expensive (and requires going through the entire list at least once) and there is more setup to the lookup but setup aside the lookup is constant time (O(1)).

Answer (score 0):

Storing the instances of your Person class in a list would be a way of doing this. You can then loop through the list to match the names.

e.g.

```
class Person():

    def __init__(self, age, weight, name):
        self.age = age
        self.weight = weight
        self.name = name


all_persons = []
all_persons.append(Person(50, 200, "John Smith"))  # add your Person instance to a list
all_persons.append(Person(40, 220, "Tom Jones"))

name_input = input("Insert the person's name: ")

for person in all_persons:  # loop through list of all Person instances
    if name_input.lower() in person.name.lower():  # lower() to handle case
        # do something with person
```